# How do I use a XSLT file as an e-mail template?

Tags: xslt

I've seen a few sharepoint developers use XSLT files instead of HTML files as their e-mail templates when they need to send out various items from lists in emails to subscribers / clients.

I have setup the XSLT as I want the email to look like when it gets sent out, but how do I get it and use it through my C# code?

Comment: Are you talking about the Alert templates?

Comment: @Wictor - No not those. This is for pure custom code only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [XslCompiledTransform class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx), it's in the .NET Fx.

Comment: Looks promising. Can you link me some good examples?

Comment: Just Google or Bing it!